# Eclipse 3,6 (Helios) referenced project has main method, cannot access from run config when targeting referencing project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects in a workspace, one is a fancy application that is configured by xml (project 1), the other contains some code specific to a task (project 2) and utilizes some classes and implements interfaces from the fancy app.

Project 1 contains the main method and is configured by an xml file to load a class from project 2 using reflection, so it needs to be launched from the context of project 2.

Project 2 references project 1 in the build path, and thus shows no errors and compiles, however when selected from the run configurations dialog, it does not show the class with a main method from project 1 as an option.

My work around for now is to generate a jar from project 1 and reference that from project 2, which then causes the class to show up.  This works, but I hate having to export the project to jar every time a change occurs in project 1.  I also hate having the EXACT same Class show up in open type twice, once from the jar, once from the project.

Is there something on top of adding the project to the build path I have to do to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Not that I know of, you could create an ant `build.xml` that way you can manage your compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch your application from project 1, just need to edit its Launch Configuration and add a project 2 at the Classpath tab.

Comment: It seems kinda of strange to reference project 1 from project 2 to compile, then project 2 from project 1 to actually run things. At least it works!  Thanks