# How do I run a main class in Eclipse from a different Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

So I have say two projects, project A and project B. Project A contains a main class which I want to run. Project B contains some classpath resources which are required and also has a reference to Project A. If I run the main class in Project A directly, it will only run it in the context of that project and won't include the classpath resources as they're in Project B.

But if I try to run Project B, I can't select the main class (as it doesn't exist in that project) and if I try right-clicking the project -> Run As -> Java Application, it doesn't come up with that main class as a valid main class. (It does come up in the similar dialog for Project A.)

This seems to be a common problem from Eclipse; I found this related question but this person is not using Maven. Also, they accepted an answer which referenced project B from project A, which breaks the encapsulation I am trying to achieve here:
[Eclipse 3,6 (Helios) referenced project has main method, cannot access from run config when targeting referencing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090140/eclipse-3-6-helios-referenced-project-has-main-method-cannot-access-from-run)

Comment: Really, if the main class in project A depends on resources in project B, it seem project A should reference project B. I have a funny feeling when you say you don’t want that.

Comment: Project B references not only project A but a whole load of other projects. If any one of them (including but not limited to project A) should want to switch implementation, they should be able to without needing to modify the other projects. Project B is the only one that would need to be modified. It's fairly standard modular design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options I can think of:

1. Use the command line to kick off the main method passing the jar in the classpath.
2. Have project A refer to project B's config rather than the other way.  [I realize you don't want to do this, but feel compelled to list it to be thorough)
3. Create a class in project B that has a main method which delegates to project A.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used option (3) - although it's annoying I have to do it this way. I can at least remove this class in production a lot more easily than I can change classpath options in production.

Answer (score 2):

So I got this working on

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

@Michael Piefel - If B depends on A then A is already in B's run config classpath under the "Maven Dependencies" classpath entry.

The issue seems to be that the ui doesn't present the class to be chosen from its search dialog.

But if you just enter the fully qualified classname into the "Main class" text field and run it will still work. :D

Comment: This behavior in Eclipse really bothers me - did you report it as a bug or saw anyone else reporting it?

Comment: Nope, its been a long time, been using intellij for the last few years, but it also seems to be degrading to a point of unusability :(

Answer (score 0):

You really just need to tweak your *Run Configurations* accordingly. In the *Classpath* tab for the run configuration you use to run the class from project A, you can add project B as a dependency. Now while running that class, all the resources from project B are included.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - but the whole point of using Maven is you're not supposed to tinker about with these things yourself ;)

Comment: I don't know .. there doesn't seem to be any point to using Maven.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about Maven, @Kidburla, but I think I know it. You are not tinkering, you just have to tell Eclipse to run the class (no matter which project it comes from) with the classpath from B (which will then include all the Maven dependencies of B, of course). It’s fairly standard run configuration handling.